# Context is lossing all the state values when document.dispatchEvent trigger in react js

Tags: reactjs, dom-events, react-context, dispatch, custom-events

I have a parent component A inside this parent component I have 2 child components B and C
Component B renders a table and component C is a search option where the user can input keywords for search and on the basis of that a list of matching items will be displayed when the user selects any of the items from the list it will get added in the Database and from component A I will be dispatching the custom event to refresh the component to show updated table to the user.

But by doing so my context state which has a list of all the keywords is losing all the state's data. Component A is wrapped in context to store the keywords data.

in my parent component this is how I am dispatching event and

```
let event = new CustomEvent('ComponentBRefresh', { bubbles: true });
      document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

in my child component, this is how I handle the refresh of table data.

```
 document.addEventListener('ComponentBRefresh', this.silentRefresh);
```

How can prevent context from losing the state and refresh the component as well.
I can not use redux due to some restrictions.